# How to load image on onload with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, image, onload

I am new with HTML and JavaScript. I am trying to load image using `onload` event through JavaScript.

My code is as below:

```
<script>
 function createImage() {

        ('testimonialhulk').src='photo.jpg';
</script>
```

and the HTML is

```
<body onload="createImage()">

<div class="testimonialhulk">

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

I have to display image in `div` tag.

Comment: but `div` tag don't have attribute `src`

Comment: what are you using pure js or jquery...you have syntax errors with both html and js

Comment: thanks Jyothi but is thr any alternative??please suggest me what can i use there?

Comment: Do you just need one image to load? Per JBA's comment, you should use an <img> tag with the src attribute. Why does it need to be in a <div> tag? I would give the <img> tag an id, then reference it in your javascript (jQuery).

Answer (score 1):

This works in my jsfiddle

```
<body onload="createImage();">
    <div id="testimonialhulk">
        Hello
    </div>
</body>
```

Js:

```
function createImage() 
{
    var myElement = document.getElementById("testimonialhulk");
    myElement.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://placehold.it/350x150')";
}
```

JS fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/wuskc68d/1/

Comment: I suggest renaming the variable to something other than `x`

Comment: Changed it to myElement  :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function createImage() {
var par = document.getElementsByClassName("testimonialhulk")[0];
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = 'put path here';
par.appendChild(img);
}
```

or use `<div id="testimonialhulk">`

```
document.getElementById('testimonialhulk')
    .innerHTML = '<img src="imageName.png" />';
```